# Cannot insert text with single quotes in Yii

Tags: yii, special-characters

I have got a Yii 1.0 project and I am trying to insert a form data using its model. Is there any configuration I need to do to escape quotes in my query?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this earlier. This is due to breaking of `query` - to solve it I used `param` method to pass `variables`:

```
 Model::model()->update(
     array('status' => 1),
     'username=:username',
     array(':username' => $model->username)
 );
```